# Req.body is Undefined while Post request through Fetch Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I  try to call the POST Api through fetch method by passing the parameter in body then I got req.body undefined on backend side(Node js side).Also when I call the Same POST api through Postman by passing the parameter in body then It work successfully(I got the req.body). backend is in node js and Front end is in React js. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Node Backend log]
[image: Browser console log]
[image: Network console in browser]
[image: Network console in browser]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../Css/Login.css'

export class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            name: "",
            password: ""
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        try {

            let result = fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'

                },
                body: { name: this.state.name, password: this.state.password }
            })

            result.then((sucess) => { console.log(sucess) })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)

        }



    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="LoginPage">
                    <div class="container Login_div">
                        <div className="Admin_panel"><h2>Admin Panel</h2></div>

                        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={this.onChange} />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.onChange} />
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: Did you install `body-parser`?

Comment: yes i installed body parser.but getting same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert you body data to JSON with `JSON.stringify`.

And also make sure the `cors` enabled on the backend side.

The issue is with `mode: 'no-cors'` , Please remove this. AS  the `application/json` is not allowed in `no-cors` mode.

> Note that mode: "no-cors" only allows a limited set of headers in the request:
>
> 1. Accept
> 2. Accept-Language
> 3. Content-Language Content-Type with a value of
>      application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
>      text/plain

Try this.

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    try {
        let result = fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.name, password: this.state.password })
        })
        result.then((sucess) => { console.log(sucess) })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: I have used JSON.stringfy but still same error occur.

Comment: Do you have enabled cors on backend side. I feel the issue is related to cors.

Comment: Can you inspect the dev console and check the network tab and see what is being send to backend.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of errors.please find the attachment above

Comment: The issue is with `mode: 'no-cors',` remove this.

Comment: If I remove the 'no-cors' then I get the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error.

Comment: Thanks alot @SohailAshraf. CORS was the problem.

I needed to install CORS in npm and enable it in the script like this
```const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://origin_address'
}));```

Answer (score 8):

Is this use `node-fetch`? So I think you need to add `JSON.stringify()` to body.

```
try {

    let result = fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode:'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Accept':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name: this.state.name, password: this.state.password })
    });

    result.then((success) => { console.log(success) });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Link refers [Node Fetch - post with json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#post-with-json). I hope it works.

**UPDATE**
If your backend is using ExpressJs make sure you added.

```js
const app = express();

// push them above the router middleware!

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: I have used JSON.stringfy but still same error occur.

Comment: @Sharadkumar I upddated my answer.

Comment: I have already used this urlencoded. I have attached the screenshot of errors.please find the attachment above.

Comment: Yeah, I see you errors, but could you provide me details of request data, maybe `400 bad request` come from you request data to server.

Answer (score 0):

Also you will needed to bind the function submitHandler at the constructor, to access to '*this*'

```
 this.submitHandler =this.submitHandler .bind(this);
```

Comment: `submitHandler` function is an arrow function, we don't need to bind an arrow function.